# Text in checkbox getting cut to 11 characters by flowlayoutplanel?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am dynamically adding checkboxs to a flowlayoutpanel and the string that is to be entered as the text is being cut to 11 characters for all of them...

```
        check.Text = ColomnName
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(check)
```

Yes  I have made the flowlayoutpanel wider

Comment: if you just put the letter "I" multiple times, can you have more than 11?

Comment: No you can not @the_lotus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior can be reproduced with brief example. Drop a button and a flow layout panel on a form. Then run the following code. Problem is not with the width flow layout panel but with the defaulted width of the check box control. You can either explicitly state the width of the control to match the flow layout panel or have it auto size.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Text As String = "This is a test with a bit of text...."
    Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Width = 300

    'Width of check box defaulted to 104
    Dim Check1 As New CheckBox
    Check1.Text = Text
    Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Check1)

    Dim Check2 As New CheckBox
    Check2.Text = Text
    Check2.Width = Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Width 
    Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Check2)

    'Another solution...
    Dim Check3 As New CheckBox
    Check3.Text = Text
    Check3.AutoSize = True
    Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Check3)
End Sub
```

Result after clicking the button...

[image: Screen capture of example display]

Comment: Great answer! I thought it was something to do with the checkboxes and their length but I was looking more for a maxlength property rather than width.